# MacOS Big Sur - How to completely change admin password (including sudo commands)

Tags: macos, terminal, big-sur

I just got a new Mac laptop at my job and the password they set it up with is very long and complex. It's very secure, but it's also a pain to type. I'm a developer so I have to use the password pretty regularly to change settings and run sudo commands.

**How do I go about completely changing the password for the admin user?**

There's only one user on the machine and I want to make sure that every single password request will accept this new password, including sudo commands in the terminal.

There are a few ways to change user, admin, and root passwords. So I want to make sure that I'm using the most thorough option to completely change the password.

Comment: A few points of clarifications (bmike's answer is correct): your user and admin password are the same - it's a single account. You should not have a root account enabled unless you specifically need it. When you do sudo, you use your user account password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the system preference pane is the best way to change password since that will update associated keychain and FileVault items as needed. Other methods can cause keychain to fall out of sync.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-the-login-password-on-mac-mchlp1550/mac

If you open help on macOS and search for change password, you should end up with the appropriate steps if online help isn’t handy for you.